# insert data in the middle of the importrange formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, googlesheets4

I have a problem please help.
I want to importrange, but in the importrange results I want to enter data and not disturb the results of the importrange.
Example
The results from importrange are in column A1 : A100
However, I want to input data in row A6, but for A7 to A20 I still run the importrange formula.
then I want to re-input A21 and for A22 up to 100 I still run the importrange formula.

I want to get a formula or script

Comment: this is not possible. A cell can either have a manually entered value or a value generated by a formula, not both.